# How to sort a table by ID number automatically?

Tags: php, sorting, row

I just want to sort my table by ID number... how can I that with the simplest way?
I want to sort that table by "1" "2" "3" automatically.. it will start 1 to 3 (from little one to bigger numbers.)

```
<table>
<tr>  
<th>ID numbers</th>  
<th>Names</th>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>haluk</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>2</td>
<td>betul</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>3</td>
<td>Erdem</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>5</td>
<td>Eylül</td>
</tr>
```

Thanks...

Comment: How do you construct the table now?

Comment: what you mean? sorry I dont understand...

Comment: Did you just type all of that in or JS or PHP outputting it or what?  If typed in, just type it in order.

Comment: it is a bit complicatd... I used ajax.. one part of table = "simple html" second one = "php output; type" ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
include('database_connection.php');
$sorgu = $baglanti->query("select * from makale ORDER BY ID;");
while ($sonuc = $sorgu->fetch_assoc())  {
?>
```

I added that code in front of my table and fetch_assoc my datas to my table.. than all ordered by ID numbers...

Answer (score 1):

To sorting the table automatically via Pure HTML seems impossible at all. You still need to use PHP to make a quick sorting. But first all the data must be inside of your database table. An to simply echo out all the info just do some simple looping

```
<?php
$bil = 1;
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM tablename";
$Query = mysqli_query($connection , $SQL);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($Query)) {
echo "
<tr><td>".$bil++."</td></tr>
";
}
?>
```

If don't understand feel free to ask

Comment: first of all thanks for kindly answer...secondly this is not sorting with orginal ID I think... this makes a numberin from 1 to endless... my mysql database I have ID number at first of table... and I want to sort by "select ID from tablename; sort table name by ID" something like that?

Comment: :) I just realize tha I answered my own question...

include('database_connection.php');  $sorgu = $baglanti->query("select * from makale ORDER BY ID;");

Comment: Oh I am very sorry because to be honest I don't understand the problems actually. My bad.  Sorry

Comment: No problem my friend... Thanks for tring to help... also please maybe can you check? :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61765612/how-to-swap-id-numbers-between-2-line